# How to add filter to <select> without <ng-options> in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, filter, ng-options

I have a select statement

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="onChange()">
        <option id="{{item.toLowerCase()}}" ng-repeat="item in someArray">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
```

and want to apply a filter on the options to show a different value in the dropdown. Any ideas?

When using ng-options it was easy (see below), but now I can't seem to get it working.

```
<select
ng-options="item as (item | filterThatIWant) for item in someArray
ng-model="selectedItem"
ng-change="onChange()>
</select>
```

Basically I just need the equivalent of the above. without the ng-options.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the same as ng-option

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="onChange()">
    <option id="{{item.toLowerCase()}}" ng-repeat="item in someArray | filterThatIWant">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-repeat for options,

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="onChange()">
    <option id="{{item.toLowerCase()}}" ng-repeat="item in someArray">{{item | filterThatIWant}}</option>
</select>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>


<select ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl"ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="onChange()">
    <option id="{{item.toLowerCase()}}" ng-repeat="item in names">{{item | myFilter}}</option>
</select>


<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
    return function(x) {
        var i, c, txt = "";
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            c = x[i];
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                c = c.toUpperCase();
            }
            txt += c;
        }
        return txt;
    };
});
app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        'Jani',
        'Carl',
        'Margareth',
        'Hege',
        'Joe',
        'Gustav',
        'Birgit',
        'Mary',
        'Kai'
        ];
});
</script>

<p>This filter, called "myFilter", will uppercase every ODD character.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**PLease run the above snippet**

[**Here is a WORKING DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/E0BCPRhAMZqOMaM1QoUX?p=preview)